# how can i make this code more efficient? need to calaulate number of combinations

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
int nis1 = 0, nis2 = 0, nis5 = 0, nis10 = 0, nis20 = 0, nis50 = 0, nis100 = 0, nis200 = 0;
long int num, count = 0, sum = 0;

while (1)
{
    printf_s("what number you like to check? (or press '0' to exit)\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);
    if (num == 0)
        break;


    for (nis200 = 0; nis200 <= num / 200; nis200++) {

        for (nis100 = 0; nis100 <= num / 100; nis100++) {

            for (nis50 = 0; nis50 <= num / 50; nis50++) {

                for (nis20 = 0; nis20 <= num / 20; nis20++) {

                    for (nis10 = 0; nis10 <= num / 10; nis10++) {

                        for (nis5 = 0; nis5 <= num / 5; nis5++) {

                            for (nis2 = 0; nis2 <= num / 2; nis2++) {

                                for (nis1 = 0; nis1 <= num; nis1++) {

                                    sum = nis200 * 200 + nis100 * 100 + nis50 * 50 + nis20 * 20 + nis10 * 10 + nis5 * 5 + nis2 * 2 + nis1 * 1;
                                    if (sum == num) {
                                        count++;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    if (sum > num)
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }


                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }


    printf_s("the number of combinations is: %d\n", count);

    count = 0;


}
```

}
//i have to build a code that with a given number by the user, how many posibillities are there to sum the number with the number:1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200.

Comment: If the code works but you seek to improve it, this belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: Look up memoization.

Comment: `scanf_s("%d", &num);` with `long int num;` is undefined behavior, so fix that first. :) Either use `%ld` or just `int num;`, the types have to match.

Comment: To give a hint, consider what happens if `nis200 * 200 == num` (in which case, all the other variables can only be zero (i.e. only the first iteration of each inner loop is needed).   Compare that with the number of iterations of each loop that your code actually runs .....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is really much too broad for Stack Overflow, which deals with more focussed coding problems than this.  For advice on improving working code, consider [codereview.se] instead - but do read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first.

Answer (score 0):

Check in each for loop if your `sum` is already above the `num` and break the loop if it is the case. Not the ultimate optimization but it makes your code much faster.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do a lot of counting from 0 to whatever.  If you use a number like 500, then your first iteration will be 0 x 200, 0 x 100 ... all the way down to 0 x 2, and then you count 1s from 0 to 500.  When you're down to your last option, you should be able to calculate how many 1s you still need.
2. For any given bill, you always count how many of it you need without regard for the bills you've already selected.  If you use a number like 500, and you already have 2 x 200, then you will never need 100 5s; you should be able to calculate the maximum number of 5s you will need.  (Keep a running total of each selection-so-far).